# When is $\left(a+\frac12\right)^n+\left(b+\frac12\right)^n$ an integer?

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number Theory Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139035/number-theory-problem)

Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then
$\left(a+\frac12\right)^n+\left(b+\frac12\right)^n$

is an integer for only finitely many positive integers n.

Comment: I don't think the title reflects the question

Comment: Thanks I was thinking a another problem--Mathematic life :)

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101221111541AAq3iD9

Comment: The problem can be rewritten as $2^n | (2a+1)^n+(2b+1)^n$. If $n$ is even then the RHS is 2 mod 4, otherwise you have to solve $(2a+1)^{2k+1}=(-2b-1)^{2k+1} \mod 2^{2k+1}$, but I am stucked here....