# When is $\bigl( \frac{a}{b} \bigr)^{3} \pm \bigl( \frac{x}{y}\bigr)^{3}$ an integer?

Tags: number-theory

I am trying solve this form, but it appears not easy problem, and also I can't find references about it.

I suppose some constrains should be stated, like "$b,y > 1$" and "$\gcd(a,b) \gcd(x/y) = 1$" .

Here some examples
$$
\left( \frac{17}{21} \right)^{3} + \left(\frac{37}{21} \right)^{3} = 6
$$
$$
\left(\frac{73}{38} \right)^{3} - \left( \frac{17}{38}\right)^{3} = 7
$$

Example with two solutions
$$
\left(\frac{36}{13}\right)^{3} - \left(\frac{17}{13}\right)^{3} = \left( \frac{109}{31}\right)^{3} - \left(\frac{90}{31}\right)^{3} = 19
$$
Solutions to this problem seems to be scarce, so can any integer be written in this form?

Thanks

******** edited feb 22 2020 ************************************

Now turning to this question.
I do not know if these formulas are known (probably yes), but since I have not seen them in books or publications, they could be of interest for someone.

I found that the equation $a^3 + b^3 = n.c^3$ can be solved in many cases immediately if this much simpler one can also be solved

$s^2t + t^2s = st(s+t) = n.k^3$ ....... [A]

having the gift that now k = 1 is not a trivial solution, but a very valid one

Once resolved (A) we immediately have this form to help

$[2(s-t)^3 + 18s^2t]^3 + [-2(s-t)^3 + 18st^2]^3 = st(s+t)[6(s^2+st+t^2)]^3$ ....... [B]

When k>1 in [A], $k^3$ goes into the right parenthesis in [B] isolating **n**

In this way, all $n = st(s+t)$ are immediately solved, and most difficult cases remains when it is necessary find value of $k^3$ to reduce **n**.

Example for s=7, t=3 -> $n=3.7(3+7)=210$

$(2(7-3)^3+18.7^2.3)^3 + (-2(7-3)^3+18.7.3^2)^3 = 210.(6(7^2+7.3+3^2))^3$

= $2774^3 + 1006^3 = 210 . 474^3$

dividing all greater common divisor $gcd(2774,1006)^3 = 8$ we have

$1387^3 + 503^3 = 210.237^3$

I didn't find a simple way to solve (A) for all **n**, especially when the value of **k** is very large, but for small **k** the work is still easy.

For example **n = 13** has no immediate solution in [A] but it has for $n = 13.42^3 = 343.8(343+8)$

s=343, t=8, $n = 13.42^3$, replacing s, t in [B] produces 
$92132206^3 - 74795614^3 = 13.42^3.722742^3$

dividing by $gcd(921322206,74795614)^3 = 8$ we have

$4606103^3 - 3739780^3 = 13.(42.361371)^3$

**RECURSION**

From [B] we have a recursive formula to find infinite solutions.

In effect, the above solution was possible because we already knew there was a previous solution $7^3+2^3 = 13.3^3$

So if $Uj^3 + Vj^3 = n.Bj^3$ then s=Uj, t=Vj and we have $n = Uj^3.Vj^3.(Uj^3+Vj^3)$ and substituting in [B]

$Uj+1^3 + Vj+1^3 = n.(Uj.Vj.Bj+1)^3$ (please somebody could help me to post j and j+1 values as subscripts?)

which is the example mentioned above

**NOTES:**

1) The formula in [B] generally cannot produce the simplest results for n, for example $5^3 + 4^3 = 7.3^3$, or $7^3 + 2^3 = 13.3^3$. Maybe these simpler results could be achieved by using complex numbers s=a+bi, t=c+di , but I found a bit difficult to solve this way.

2) In a table for **n** up to 100 , **I was unable** to solve [B] ​​for n = 31,67,71,89 which indeed have solutions

$31 = (137/42)^3 + (-65/42)^3$

$67 = (5353/1323)^3 + (1208/1323)^3$

$71 = (53/13)^3 + (36/13)^3$

$89 = (197/43)^3 + (-126/43)^3$

Tested values ​​were s, t <= 10,000

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: All your examples have $b=y$. Are there other examples with $\gcd(b,y) = 1$? I suspect not.

Comment: I ran a little program letting b , y  free, but all solutions show b = y . This could be proved or disproved.

Comment: What is your question?  'Can any integer be written in this form?'  Is that your question?  If so, you should change your title.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the question (although it is an obvious extension). The question is "when this form can be solved" ? . Parametric form to a,b,x,y for instance could help a lot.

Comment: I found this one in the same way http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293731/when-is-lefta-frac12-rightn-leftb-frac12-rightn-an-integer?rq=1

Comment: if $b = y$, and $(\frac{x}{y})^3 + (\frac{a}{b})^3 = n$ then at least $n$ cannot be a perfect cube.

Comment: you are right, I forgot Fermat, constrain is "...when n is not cube"

Comment: Suppose $b = y$ and $a^3 + x^3=nb^3$. Then there exist an $m$ such that $m^3$ is closest to $n$, i.e $n = m^3 + k$. In such a case we have $a^3 + x^3+(-mb)^3=kb^3$. Now if $k$ is a perfect cube as well then the smallest integer solutions of equations of the form $u^3+v^3+w^3= s^3$ are on this link.
 http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$x^3+y^3 = N$$
or,
$$\left(\frac{36N+v}{6u}\right)^3+\left(\frac{36N-v}{6u}\right)^3 =N$$ 
This simplifies to the well-known elliptic curve

> $$u^3-432N^2 =v^2\tag1$$

Solvable $N$ are given by [A159843](http://oeis.org/A159843) as

$$N = 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 33,\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

The reference you want is Henri Cohen, *Number Theory Volume I: Tools and Diophantine Equations*

Here is a [link to PAGE 377](https://books.google.com/books?id=qxCWoFO-oxYC&pg=PA377&lpg=PA377&dq=henri%20cohen%20number%20theory%20there%20are%20infinitely%20many%20integers%20that%20are%20not%20the%20sum%20of%20two%20cubes%20of%20rational%20numbers&source=bl&ots=2DQ8KjNIiJ&sig=koR5TSdKZ4DTmbzM-IPEjiUVGdA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2vpe-rNLKAhVC22MKHWVxA0wQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=henri%20cohen%20number%20theory%20there%20are%20infinitely%20many%20integers%20that%20are%20not%20the%20sum%20of%20two%20cubes%20of%20rational%20numbers&f=false)

Mostly you want sections 6.4.5 and 6.4.6 , pages 373-380. He gives a number of references, also Proposition 6.4.20 with proof as an exercise, that says exactly when a number is the sum of two integer cubes.  As far as constructions, he mostly refers to techniques using elliptic curves. The conjecture 6.4.21 is this: any positive squarefree number $n \equiv 4,6,7,8 \pmod 9$ is the sum of two rational cubes; the count of numbers $n \equiv 1,2,3,5 \pmod 9$ that are the sum of two rational cubes, with $n < X$ for large $X,$ is about 
$$ c X^{5/6} \left( \log X \right)^{\sqrt 3 / 2 - 1/8} $$
He then says that it is more natural to talk about cubefree numbers, but the conditions are more difficult to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Some parametric forms found for this problem

a)

$(5+m)^3 + (4-m)^3 = (7+m(m+1)).3^3$

examples

m=206  $(211/3)^3 - (202/3)^3 = 42649$

m=4321 $(4326/3)^3 - (4317/3)^3 = 18675369$

b)

$(4+m)^3 + (4-m)^3 = (16+3m^2).2^3$

examples

m=4321 $(4325/2)^3 - (4317/2)^3 = 56013139$

m=1001 $(1005/2)^3 - (1001/2)^3 = 1509015$

c)

$(9+m)^3 + (9-m)^3 = (54+2m^2).3^3$

examples

m=4321 $(4330/3)^3 - (4312/3)^3 = 37342136$

m=1001 $(1010/3)^3 - (992/3)^3 = 2004056$

d)

$(36+m)^3 + (36-m)^3 = (432+m^2).6^3$

examples

m=4321 $(4357/6)^3 - (4285/6)^3 = 18671473$

m=1001 $(1037/6)^3 - (965/6)^3 = 1002433$

I don´t know if these forms could be unified in a more general one using extra parms

Answer (score 0):

Now turning to this problem,

suppose $a^3 + b^3 = N.c^3$

there is solution for $x = 2+3w , w= ...-2,1,0,1,2...$

$N = x^3-1$  (for instance N = 7 , 65 , 124...)

$c = (1+x^3)/3$

$a = x(c-1)$

$b= x^3-c$

example: $w = 0 -> x = 2 , N = 2^3 - 1 = 7 , c = (1+2^3)/3 = 3 , a = 2(3-1) = 4 , b = 2^3-3 = 5$

$4^3 + 5^3 = 7.3^3$

example: $w = -2 -> x = -4 , N = -65 , c = -21 , a = 88 , b = -43$

$88^3 - 43^3 = (-65)(-21)^3 = 65.21^3$

Answer (score 0):

Because $X^3+Y^3=Z^3$ has no rational solution with $XYZ\ne0$ one must have  $$(ay)^3+(bx)^3=A(by)^3\hspace{10mm}(*)$$
The equation $$X^3+Y^3=AZ^3\hspace{10mm}(**)$$ is an elliptic curve whitout torsion for $A\ne1,2$ so if there is a rational solution then there are infinitely many rational solutions. Among these not all have the form of $(*)$, naturally.

It can be proven that for all rational $a,b,c$ such that $a+b=c$ the equation $X^3+Y^3=abcZ^3$ has rational solutions.

The most important work about the equation $(**)$ is the classic Selmer's monography "The diophantine equation $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$ Act Math. (Stockh.) **85** (1951) p.203-362.

Comment: Obviously $A$ above is an integer cube-free factor.