# How connect $x^2+xy+y^2$ to $j^3*4*n-27 = t^2$

Tags: number-theory

$x^2 + xy + y^2 = (x^3 - y^3)/(x - y)$

Now let me show a subject not connected with above form (at least in some known way).

By trying solve equation

$1 \cdot 4 \cdot n - 27 = t^2$  ($n,t$ integers)

$n=(7+(m(m+1))$ works fine, since $4(7+m(m+1)) - 27 = 28 + 4m^2 + 4m - 27 = (2m+1)^2$

so $t = 2m+1$

Now look "$1 \cdot 4 \cdot n$" at left, the "1" part really means "$1^{3} \cdot 4 \cdot n$" , so I searched which other $j^{3} \cdot 4 \cdot n - 27$ forms could produce perfect squares.

I wrote a tiny BASIC program to check whether

$j^{3} \cdot 4 \cdot n - 27 = t^2$  ($j,n,t$ integers) ... (A)

and found the following $j$ solving it for some $n$ (and only those $j$ and no others)

1, 3, 7, 13, 19, 21, 31, 37, 39, 43, 49, 57, 61, 67, 73, 79, 91, 93, 97, 103, 109, 111, 127, 129, 133, 139, 147, 151, 157, 163, 169, 181, 183, 193, 199, 201, 211, 217, 219, 223, 229, 237, 241, 247, 259, 271, 273, 277, 283, 291, 301, 307, 309, 313, 327, 331, ..... (more)

For every "$j$" found, there are probably infinite "$n$" to produce perfect squares (I suppose, but couldn´t prove it)

I searched on database sequence integers oeis.org for this sequence, and it is exactly the sequence generated by

$x^2 + xy + y^2$  (oeis sequence A034017)

Some $j$ wait for a big $n$ to show the first solution, ex.  $j=259$ starts with $n=4225513$ to compute $t=17136391$

$259^{3} \cdot 4 \cdot 4225513 - 27 = 17136391^2$

Now the question, why should $j$ present this pattern $j = x^2+xy+y^2$ ?

Anybody can check list of $j$ by running this tiny UBASIC program for some hours. It will search all integers to 500 and will list only those $j$ which solves (A) first time.

> 800   for J=1 to 500
>
> 900   V=J*J*J
>
> 1000   for N=1 to 5000000
>
> 1100   X=V*4*N-27
>
> 1240   T=sqrt(abs(X))
>
> 1250   if T=int(T+0.0000000001) then print J;:cancel for:goto 1400
>
> 1300   next N
>
> 1400   next J

Comment: what is the question you are trying to solve?

Comment: If possible I would like to replace "j" by x^2+xy+y^2 on (A) and develop all the sentences to arrive to some t^2 , but I can't , I just am guessing things after running a basic program.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote
$$ t^2 + 27 = 4 n j^3. $$ This means that $t$ is odd and $t^2 + 27 \equiv 4 \pmod 8.$ This means, in turn, that $n,j$ are both odd.

Meanwhile, if we have odd prime $p,$ with
$$ x^2 + 27 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p, $$ it follows that, whenever $(-3|p) = -1,$ both $$ x, y \equiv 0 \pmod p. $$
Therefore, since we demand $y=0,$ we have demanded that $(-3|p) = 1.$ By quadratic reciprocity, this means either $p=3$ or $(p|3) = 1.$ That is, either $p=3$ or $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$

Both $n$ and $j$ are products of such primes. $u^2 + uv + v^2$ is of class number one and represents all such primes, and represents all products of such primes. That is, you are entitled to write $n = u^2 + uv + v^2$ and $j = x^2 + xy + y^2$

Let's see. For any such $j$ and $n,$ both $j^3$ and $4n$ can be written as
$r^2 + 27 s^2.$ This is not obvious. The trouble comes when you try to force this $s=1.$

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that you wanted to specify $j$ first and only then find an $n.$ This requires some knowledge but is algorithmic.

First, $259 = 7 \cdot 37.$ We automatically have some ways to write $259 = x^2 + 3 y^2.$ However, the class group of discriminant $-108$ has three forms, $x^2 + 27 y^2,$ $4x^2 + 2 x y + 7 y^2,$ $4x^2 - 2 x y + 7 y^2.$

As it happens, $$ 259 = 4^2 + 27 \cdot 3^2. $$ We need to primitively represent $259^3.$ Squared,
$$ 259^2 = 227^2 + 27 \cdot 24^2. $$ Finally,
$$ 259^3 = 2852^2 + 27 \cdot 585^2, $$
with $$  \gcd(2852,585) = 1.$$
We use some version of an extended euclidean algorithm (I use simple continued fractions) to find
$$  2852 \cdot 8 -  585 \cdot 39 = 1.  $$
The $8$ is unfortunate, as $39^2 + 27 \cdot 8^2$ is not a multiple of $4.$ We switch from $(-39,8)$ to $(-39 - 2852, 8 + 585) = (-2891, 593 )$ and check that
$$ 2852 \cdot 593 -  585 \cdot 2891 = 1,  $$
which works.
Now we do have
$$ 4n = 2891^2 + 27 \cdot 593^2 = 17852404  $$
and
$$ n = 4463101  $$

So far, we have $j^3$ represented as $x^2 + 27 y^2$ with $(x,y)$ as $(2852,585),$ and $4n$ as $(2891,593).$ From Brahmagupta's identity we get
$4nj^3$ represented as
$$ ( 2852 \cdot 2891 + 27 \cdot 585 \cdot 593, \; \;2852 \cdot 593 -  585 \cdot 2891 ),  $$ that is
$$  (17611567, \; \; 1  \; ).   $$ That is,
$$ 4nj^3 = t^2 + 27  $$
with $t = 17611567.$

Things change when representing $j^3$ as $x^2 + 27 y^2$ when we begin with some $j = 4 u^2 + 2 uv + 7 v^2.$ We still use composition in the class group, but it does look a little different from $j = r^2 + 27 s^2.$ For your main example, we could have begun with $259 = 4 u^2 + 2 uv + 7 v^2,$ with $(u,v) = (6,-5).$

Did some calculations. When we have  $j = 4 u^2 + 2 uv + 7 v^2,$ one way of writing $j^3 = x^2 + 27 y^2$ is with
$$ x =  8u^3 + 6u^2 v - 39 u v^2 - 10 v^3, \; \; y =  6 u^2 v + 3 u v^2 - 3 v^3. $$
Starting with $259$ as $(6,-5),$ this leads to $259^3$ as $(3952,-255),$ and we can repeat the bit about gcd and so on.
Continued fractions give
$$ 3952 (-2) + 255 (31) = 1. $$
Once again, the even $(-2)$ is bad, so we switch to
$$ 3952 \cdot 253 - 255 \cdot 3921 = 1. $$
This leads us to $4nj^3 = t^2 + 27,$ with 
$$ t = 3952 \cdot 3921 + 27 \cdot 255 \cdot 253 = 17237697  $$
Also
$$ n =4275621  $$

Anyway, all algorithmic, and those algorithms can produce some fairly large numbers, but not enormous.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your explanations, I am still reading carefully your posts.

First of all, let me say this problem is part of another which I posted some months ago in this link

[When is $\bigl( \frac{a}{b} \bigr)^{3} \pm \bigl( \frac{x}{y}\bigr)^{3}$ an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524059/when-is-bigl-fracab-bigr3-pm-bigl-fracxy-bigr3-an-inte)

When searching some parametric forms to problem in above link, I reached the expression

$j^3.4.n - 27 = t^2$

which when solved for $j=1$ and $n=(7+m(m+1))$ lead me to

$(5+m)^3 + (4-m)^3 = (7+m(m+1)).3^3$

or else

$(5+m)^3 / 3^3 + (4-m)^3 / 3^3 = 7+m(m+1)$

This form solves infinite cases, like m=0 to $(5/3)^3+(4/3)^3=7$ or m=6 to $(11/3)^3-(2/3)^3=49$ , but there are still "infinite x infinite" cases to solve , one for every j.

By analyzing j=2 ,it appeared difficult to me, so I take next j

For $j=3$ I found $n=1+3m(m+1)$ which works fine giving $t=9(2m+1)$ since

$3^3.4.(1+3m(m+1)) - 27 = 27[4(1+3m(m+1)) - 1] = 27(12m^2+12m+3) = [9(2m+1)]^2$

but unfortunately this j leads to an indentity instead a solution, because denominators cancell all of them

Now comes the moment when I asked "which other j produces squares when applied to $j^3.4.n$ ? . I made this question preventing some hard job to find j=f(z) for some z, which would produce squares.

I supposed these j´s would follow a single variable pattern (z), so it would be relatively easy to assemble a more general form to solve those cubic fractions, by includind now the parametric form of j in the same way I included parametric form of n.

I wrote that basic program to learn it, and result appeared in the form of the sequence j=1,3,7,13... Next I run to database of sequences (OEIS) to see what could be that thing, and here is when my surprise came, because j is not a single variable function, but a two variables function, which complicates a lot the searching for more general form.

For next j=7 , things turns to be very more complicated (to find f(n)), so just think about the task for j=13,19,21 ....

Now about your analysis of j=259 , this is an example I used to show how can be difficult to find the first "n" for given "j" . 259 is only one of those elements in the sequence, there are other examples also which delay a lot to produce first "n" like j=223 or j=229 which give first solution for n=1517139 and n=2582431

$223^3.4.1517139 - 27 = 8203515^2$

$229^3.4.2582431 - 27 = 1137753^2$

Increasing difficulty to find first solution doesn´t follow j size. Some big "js" have first solution with little n, like j=1011 which starts with n=28009

$1011^3.4.28009 - 27 = 10759833^2$

Now turning to j=259 , it appears solutions of these problems try to group in "clumps" , look for the first 8 solutions of 259, the first four "ts" more or less 1/3 of the second four "ts".

1- n=  4225513  t= 17136391

2- n=  4275621  t= 17237697 (your solution)

3- n=  4411903  t= 17510261

4- n=  4463101  t= 17611567 (your solution)

5- n=  38735883 t= 51884349

6- n=  38887297 t= 51985655

7- n=  39296143 t= 52258219

8- n=  39448647 t= 52359525

I found these solutions with a tiny change in the listed basic program.

Comment: If you want to reply to someone, you need to also include a comment after one of their answers, saying that you have a long message as an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

For this question, everything you want can be written in terms of (positive) binary quadratic forms with integer coefficients. You need to know that the discriminant $-108$ possesses  imprimitive forms, $2x^2 + 2 xy + 14 y^2$ and $3x^2 + 9 y^2$ and $6x^2 + 6 xy + 6 y^2,$ along with the three primitive forms that make up the class group,

$$ x^2 + 27 y^2, $$
$$ 4 x^2 + 2 xy + 7 y^2, $$
$$ 4 x^2 - 2 xy + 7 y^2. $$

You need to know something about Gauss/Dirichlet composition. I recommend some modern books, i especially like Buell, *Binary Quadratic Forms*. For the part of your problem that requires proving divisibility, there is a book from 1929 by Leonard Eugene Dickson, *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*. You need pages 91-95 in particular. If you are patient, you should be able to recover all the $8$ or so solutions you found to $4nj^3 = t^2 + 27$ by these methods. I admit, it will get more difficult when writing $j^3 = 4 u^2 + 2 uv + 7 v^2$ to find $4n = 4 x^2 - 2 xy + 7 y^2$ for $4nj^3 = r^2 + 27 s^2$ with the restriction $s=\pm1.$

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much W. Jagy, after your msg I recalled I have the three volumes of Dickson (printed 1971) and there (vol II pag 572) I found an entire chapter "sum of two rational cubes". I am reading now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, we could have found your smallest $n$ and $t$ by a little more imaginative bookkeeping.

$$  \gcd(2852,585) = 1.$$
We use some version of an extended euclidean algorithm (I use simple continued fractions) to find
$$  2852 \cdot 8 -  585 \cdot 39 = 1.  $$
That is, the determinant of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2852 & 585 \\
39 & 8
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is $1.$ In the other answer, in order to get rid of the even $8,$ i added the first row to the second to get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2852 & 585 \\
2891 & 593
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Nothing wrong with that. However i could just as well have subtracted the first row from the second, giving
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2852 & 585 \\
-2813 & -577
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The minus signs do not matter here. 
This does give us

$$ 4n = 2813^2 + 27 \cdot 577^2 = 16902052  $$
and
$$ n = 4225513  $$