# Proof read from "A problem seminar"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, self-learning

May you help me judging the correctness of my proof?:

Show that the if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$
is integer for only finintely many positive integers $n$

We want $n$ so that
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\equiv0\pmod{1}$$
So we know by the binomial theorem that

$(an+b)^k\equiv b^n\pmod{n}$ for positive $k$

Then,
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\equiv(1/2)^n\pmod{1}$$
and similarly with the $b$

So 
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\left(b+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\equiv 2*(1/2)^n\pmod{1}$$
Therefore, we want $2*(1/2)^n$ to be integer, so that $2^n|2$
clearly, the only positive option is $n=1$
(Editing, my question got prematurely posted. Done)

Comment: You can't actually do arithmetic modulo $1$ that way.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Is that a issue of "notation", or could you point the line of my mistake?

Comment: You don't have if $x\equiv y\pmod 1$ then $ax\equiv ay\pmod 1$. For example, $x=\frac{1}{2}, y=\frac{3}{2}, a=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Specifically, you don't have $(a+1/2)^n \equiv 1/2^n\pmod 1$. Try $a=1,n=3$.  You get $$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3 = \frac{27}{8}\equiv \frac{3}{8}\not\equiv \frac{1}{8}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$$

Comment: Oh I see now, with my "proof" the problem was just too easy to be true, that is why I posted it.

Comment: Modular arithmetic only works over the integers - if you try it with rationals, you don't get well-defined operations. We sometimes abuse notation and write $\frac{1}{5}\equiv 3\pmod 7$, for example, when we mean $1\equiv 3\cdot 5\pmod 7$. We are not really talking about the rational number $\frac{1}{5}$...

Comment: The notation about multiplicative inverses kind of confused me about thinking I could use rationals in modular arithmetic(using $5^{-1}$ is kind of standard notation). Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, $5^{-1}$ is much better notation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number Theory Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139035/number-theory-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our expression can be written as 
$$\frac{(2a+1)^n+(2b+1)^n}{2^n}.$$

If $n$ is even, then $(2a+1)^n$ and $(2b+1)^n$ are both the squares of odd numbers.

Any odd perfect square is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$. So their sum is congruent to $2$ modulo $8$, and therefore cannot be divisible by any $2^n$ with $n\gt 1$.

So we can assume that $n$ is odd. For odd $n$, we have the identity 
$$x^n+y^n=(x+y)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}y+\cdots +y^{n-1}).$$
Let $x=2a+1$ and $y=2b+1$. Note that $x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}y+\cdots +y^{n-1}$ is a sum of an odd number of terms, each odd, so it is odd.

Thus the highest power of $2$ that divides $(2a+1)^n+(2b+1)^n$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $(2a+1)+(2b+1)$. Since $(2a+1)+(2b+1)\ne 0$, there is a largest $n$ such that our expression is an integer.

**Remark:** The largest $n$ such that our expression is an integer can be made quite  large.    You might want to see for example what happens if we  let $2a+1=2049$ and $2b+1=2047$. Your proposed proof suggests, in particular, that $n$ cannot be greater than $1$.

I suggest that when you are trying to write out a number-theoretic argument, you avoid fractions as much as possible and deal with integers only.

Comment: Your solution solves the problem and your counterexample explicitly shows my proof is wrong, (and with the help of Thomas Andrews I see where I messed it up). Thank you and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Andre gave you a solution, but you wanted proofreading, so I'll point out two mistakes you've made (I'm not saying there aren't more :-)).

First, modulo arithmetic assumes you're working with integers, so it cannot be applied on rationals.

Second, when getting from

$$(an+b)^n\equiv b^n\pmod{n}$$

to

$$\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\equiv(1/2)^n\pmod{1}$$

You put $n = 1$, but just in some spots (but left it unchanged in the exponents). You cannot use formulas like that. It's like going from

$$n = n$$

and then substituting the first $n$ with $1$, getting

$$n = 1.$$

Of course you'll get $n = 1$ when you use it like that.

Comment: Oh, somehow I mentally was talking about different $n$s(the $n$ in the exponent could be any integer $k$), I will edit that :)