# Show that if a and b are positive integers, then $(a + \frac12)^n + (b + \frac12)^n$ is an integer for only ﬁnitely many positive integers n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I stumbled upon this problem when reading the resource provided by AoPS, on [Number Theory.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/SatoNT.pdf)

Here is the problem:

Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then

$$\left(a + \frac12\right)^n + \left(b + \frac12\right)^n$$

is an integer for only ﬁnitely many positive integers $n$.

I'm unsure on how to begin - any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: (Although the other problem should probably be edited to receive a more appropriate title)

Comment: The question has several answers [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139035/number-theory-problem)